# PHP eval and dependency injection

Tags: php, dependency-injection, eval

I am writing a web application, which I want to be be "scriptable" - meaning that I want users to be able to write little snippets of code to add additional functionality.

The script to be run, simply returns a boolean, indicating whether a condition has been met - however, the logic depends on interrogating objects in the main block - so I need a way of injecting the environment in which `eval` is being called - into the script being interpreted.

Putting security concerns aside for a moment, this is what I want to do.

```
/* script pseudo code */
if object1.date() - today() < SOME_CONSTANT 
    return true;
else
   if object2.field1 == 123 && oject1.date() > object2.field2
       return true;
   else
       return false;

/* Main block of code */
$obj1 = New path\to\Object1();
$obj2 = New Path\To\Object2();

$result = eval($script);

if $result
    doSomething();
```

My questions then is:

How do I inject the environment into a string that is to be eval'd, so that I may access the object in the expression being evaluated?

Comment: You could use a `global` statement to add all the objects they should be able to interrogate to the local scope.

Comment: @Barmar: Could you please elaborate with a little snippet?. I'm more of a C/C++/Python guy.

Comment: I'm not sure I understand the problem, what do you have trouble accessing? Everything seems to be available / the environment set up: http://codepad.viper-7.com/p5kmZF

Answer (score 0):

The `global` statement makes global variables available inside a function. So put:

```
global $var1, $var2, $var3, ...;
```

in your function that calls `eval`, where these are all the global variables that the snippets should be able to access.

Comment: Ok, thanks. I'll try this just to make sure it works in my scenrio, and then I'll accept your answer. Cheers